# Makefile:605 in caffe make

Tags: makefile, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

When I make caffe makefile with command `make all -j4`, there is an error on line 605 of makeprofile, Im not sure is there anything wrong or not, I didn't edit this line. It seem to be a wrong version of cuda? or for other reason...

error message：

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/swish_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cu
nvcc fatal   : Option '--generate-code arch=-gencode', missing code
NVCC src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cu
nvcc fatal   : Option '--generate-code arch=-gencode', missing code
nvcc fatal   : Option '--generate-code arch=-gencode', missing code
Makefile:605: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/swish_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/swish_layer.o] Error 1
Makefile:605: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.o] Error 1
nvcc fatal   : Option '--generate-code arch=-gencode', missing code
Makefile:605: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o] Error 1
```

environment：

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
CUDA Version 10.0.130
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

Comment: These messages are simply make telling you that the compile failed.  You have to post the failure messages from the compiler if you want help solving that problem.

Comment: oh sorry, I have complete the error message,so is there something wrong with nvcc?

Comment: I assume.   I don't know what nvcc is or what those options mean. Maybe someone familiar with caffe will know.

Comment: fine..thx anyway

Comment: For some reason, the SM compute capability code is not provided to `nvcc`, It must be something like `-gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62`

Comment: See this post for detailed explanation on `arch` and `code` options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656294/cuda-how-to-use-arch-and-code-and-sm-vs-compute

Comment: Please, update the question with the variables in your `Makefile.config`.

Comment: umm...actually I have installed caffe2 by pytorch instead, but still thank you for advise I will try it later and update the config profile, another reason I thought maybe is CUDA 10.0, I will also try older version later