# Cuda multiple threads incrementing same value

Tags: cuda

I have a vector in device memory that multiple threads are modifying and I cannot gaurantee that two threads won't access the same element of the vector at the same time. I have a GeForce GTX 1080 Ti and I'm running CUDA version 12.4 and driver version 550.54.14.

I created a simple example to demonstrate. The resulting output is `1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 0` when I expected this `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`. I've seen people use `atomicAdd` so I replaced `x[idx] += 1.0;` with `atomicAdd(&x[idx],1.0);` but the compiler says there is no overloaded function "atomicAdd" mathes the argument list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

__device__ void increment(double *x, int start, int span) {
  for (int idx = start; idx < start + span; idx++) {
    x[idx] += 1.0;
  }
}

__global__ void test01(double *x, int N) {
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if (idx >= 10)
    return;

  increment(x, idx, 10);
}

int main(void) {
  int N = 20;
  double *x;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(double));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 0.0;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  test01<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(x, N);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // print output
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%0.0f ", x[i]);
  printf("\n");

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) : *"The 64-bit floating-point version of `atomicAdd()` is only supported by devices of compute capability 6.x and higher"* . Do you have such a device and is the code compiled to support them?

Comment: "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti" is a 6.x device. So I guess you are missing the architecture specification for `nvcc`. See [CUDA: How to use -arch and -code and SM vs COMPUTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657430/10107454).

Comment: I was just using `nvcc example.cu` to compile and now that I've specified `--gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61` it compiles with `atomicAdd` correctly and generates the expected output. Thank you @paleonix