# CUDA: safeCall() Runtime API error invalid device symbol

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, tesla

I'm trying to run the `cudaSift` in [CudaSift](https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift) project with a Nvidia Tesla M2090 on a remote machine with CUDA 7.5. The machine has 4 of these GPUs, but I'm quite sure from the debuggining that the initialization is done correctly, anyway this is the code:

```
void InitCuda(int devNum)
{
  int nDevices;
  cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
  if (!nDevices) {
    std::cerr << "No CUDA devices available" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  devNum = std::min(nDevices-1, devNum);
  deviceInit(devNum);  
  cudaDeviceProp prop;
  cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, devNum);
  printf("Device Number: %d\n", devNum);
  printf("  Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
  printf("  Memory Clock Rate (MHz): %d\n", prop.memoryClockRate/1000);
  printf("  Memory Bus Width (bits): %d\n", prop.memoryBusWidth);
  printf("  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): %.1f\n\n",
     2.0*prop.memoryClockRate*(prop.memoryBusWidth/8)/1.0e6);
}
```

I use cmake to generate the makefile, and the `make` file generate `cudaSift` without any error.

Anyway, when I run it, the following error is returned:

```
safeCall() Runtime API error in file </ghome/rzhengac/Downloads/CudaSift-Maxwell/cudaSiftH.cu>, line 42 : invalid device symbol.
```

At line 42 of [`cudaSiftH.cu`](https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift/blob/Maxwell/cudaSiftH.cu) it is:

```
safeCall(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_PointCounter, &totPts, sizeof(int)));
```

Where:

```
__device__ unsigned int d_PointCounter[1];
int totPts = 0;
```

This is the code printed by `InitCuda` (which make quite sure that everything is fine during initialization):

```
Device Number: 0
  Device name: Tesla M2090
  Memory Clock Rate (MHz): 1848
  Memory Bus Width (bits): 384
  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): 177.4
```

**SOLUTION:**

As suggested in the comments, I was compiling with the wrong architecture: I had to change each `sm_35` in [`CMakeList.txt`](https://github.com/Celebrandil/CudaSift/blob/Maxwell/CMakeLists.txt) into `sm_20`, and this is the result:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(cudaSift)
set(cudaSift_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(cudaSift_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(cudaSift_VERSION_PATCH 0)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${cudaSift_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${cudaSift_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${cudaSift_VERSION_PATCH}")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
include(CPack)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA)
if (NOT CUDA_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "CUDA not found. Project will not be built.")
endif(NOT CUDA_FOUND)

if (WIN32)
  set(EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS "/DVERBOSE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ")
  list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_20;--compiler-options;-O2;-DVERBOSE") 
endif()
if (UNIX)
  if (APPLE)
    set(EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS "-DVERBOSE -msse2")
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_20;--compiler-options;-O2;-DVERBOSE") 
  else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -msse2 ")
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-lineinfo;--compiler-options;-O2;-DVERBOSE") 
  endif()
endif()

set(cuda_sources
  # dynamic.cu
  cudaImage.cu  
  cudaImage.h  
  cudaSiftH.cu 
  cudaSiftH.h  
  matching.cu  
  cudaSiftD.h  
  cudaSift.h  
  cudautils.h
)  

set(sources
  geomFuncs.cpp  
  mainSift.cpp
)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
)

SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

cuda_add_executable(cudasift ${cuda_sources} ${sources} OPTIONS -arch=sm_20)

set_target_properties(cudasift PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_FLAGS "${EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS}"               
)

target_link_libraries(cudasift
  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a ${OpenCV_LIBS} 
)

install(FILES 
  ${cuda_sources} 
  ${sources}
  cudaSiftD.cu
  CMakeLists.txt
  Copyright.txt
  DESTINATION .
)
install(FILES data/left.pgm data/righ.pgm
  DESTINATION data
)
```

Comment: From your other question I conclude that you compiled with `sm_30`. Your GPU is compute capability 2.0, i.e. compile with `sm_20`.

Comment: You are right sir, I had to change the `CMakeLists.txt` as described in the **SOLUTION** section of my updated answer. Could you check it please? Another error has occured (I'll open another question about it and I'll it here) and maybe it's because of this editing.

Comment: BTW if you'll post it as answer I'll chose it, cheers!

Comment: This question is a duplicate and was answered many times, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33126293/5085250.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939713/cuda-unknown-error) is the new question that I was talking about. If you could check it, it would be much appreciated