# How can nvcc compile with multi gen-code?

Tags: gpu, nvcc

nvcc can be used like this with multi gencode?

nvcc vec_add.cu -o vec_add -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35, -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70

does the command line mean that the final target "vec_add" can support for plartform with compute compatibility 20,35,70. 
but maybe there is a conflict, for example the compute compatibility below 5.2 does't support half precision, like the function

Comment: This may solve part of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17599585/7413964

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35657430/7413964